# How can I pass any number of arguments in User define function in C?

Tags: c, function

How can I pass any number of arguments in User define function in C?what is the prototype of that function?It is similar to printf which can accept any number of arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Look [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) for an example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int maxof(int, ...) ;
void f(void);

main(){
        f();
        exit(EXIT SUCCESS);
}

int maxof(int n args, ...){
        register int i;
        int max, a;
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap, n args);
        max = va_arg(ap, int);
        for(i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
                if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
                        max = a;
        }

        va_end(ap);
        return max;
}

void f(void) {
        int i = 5;
        int j[256];
        j[42] = 24;
        printf("%d\n",maxof(3, i, j[42], 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a function is calle variadic, but such functions are much less useful than they might at first seem. The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) on the topic is not bad, and has C code.

The basic problem with such functions is that the number of parameters cannot in fact be variable - they are must be fixed at compile time by a known parameter. This is obvious in printf:

printf( "%s %d", "Value is", 42 );

The number of % specifiers must match the number of actual values, and this is true for all other uses of variadic functions in C, in one form or another.